# SpringBoot gitHub config server not able to read from folder in Repo

Tags: github, spring-boot, config

I was getting my hands into spring boot with using a git based config file.
[This](https://github.com/praveen2710/MicroServices) is my repo.
In here I have some config files inside tolls-config folder this does retrieve the config file

But when in the tutorial [this](https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls) repo is used it works

API call :

> localhost:8888/s1rates/default

My Questions

1. Do I need to modify the API call
2. Should my uri be pointing to specific folder in repo( I tried putting folder URL and it gives a 500)
3. Every config file has to been its own repo ( there is no way
   around it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loked at your repo and it seems that you misspelled the property for `searchPaths` instead of `search-paths` like you have in your config.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
          searchPaths: foo,bar*
```